# overriding localization key values based on custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a requirement where the application needs to supply localization value for a key to a custom framework to set value for different languages. I am just curious how is that possible without knowing the visibility of such key pairs within the framework.

Comment: Please clarify: there is a framework with a Localizable.strings file and you as framework consumer want to override one or more values in there?

Comment: @fruitcoder yes that's correct.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without swizzling or other runtime magic. The entire `NSLocalizedString` Api is completely readonly so 'give me a String for key/table/bundle'. You cannot even override this for your own bundle (everything in the Bundle is readonly). The framework either has to provide a way for framework consumers to change the String or you have to change access the components inside the framework via private apis (like a label by traversing the view hierarchy). Otherwise, swizzling might be the only option

Comment: do you think if I expose APIs through protocol should be ideal in this case then?

Comment: Are you the framework author? It depends on what kind of component you want to customize and how much of it. You could have a protocol similar to a data source that queries different Strings for you components.